# Adobe DPS: can you allow user to split screen?

Tags: adobe-dps

A "pre-sales" question. Say you want to produce an ebook of commentary on Shakespeare's sonnets. In the text you would focus on one poem (and might want to switch to a comparable poem), but you want the commentary to be visible at the same time. Being able to slice larger screens into 2 or 3 panes, with the ability to sync would be idea. I haven't seen an ebook capable of this yet, but DPS seems fairly powerful, but without that feature it is worthless.

Answer (score 0):

DPS allow you to place HTLM Article instead of InDesign Article.
By adding some Javascript in you article, you can then control how much slice you want to add, by controlling the DOM.

Also with the Multi State Object in InDesign Overlays, meaning that you content is static, you can show or hide additional content.